Annotating HiC interactions using HOMER tool
I am working with HiC data of cotton. I have successfully generated significant Interactions using HOMER tool and now am trying to annotate the interations. The interactions file generated by HOMER is as per the given format on its website. After that I loaded a custom genome for cotton, as it is not an in-built genome in HOMER, using the loadGenome.pl script. Command: loadGenome.pl -name TM1 -fasta /home/angad/Vikash/HiC_Cotton/TM1/TM1.fna -gtf /home/angad/Vikash/HiC_Cotton/TM1/output.gtf -org cotton
After loading my custon genome I used the annotateInteractions.pl script to annotate the interactions. Command: annotateInteractiobs.pl /home/angad/Vikash/HiC_Cotton/HOMER/annotation -res 10000
The output file generated has no information in the Detailed Annotation, Gene name, Gene alias columns although all these details are present in the gtf file. How can I annotate my interactions so that all the required information is present in these fields. I also tried loading the cotton genome using updateUCSCGenomeAnnotations.pl but that doesn't work either for cotton genome.
I am working with HiC data of cotton. I have successfully generated significant Interactions using HOMER tool and now am trying to annotate the interations. The interactions file generated by HOMER is as per the given format on its website. After that I loaded a custom genome for cotton, as it is not an in-built genome in HOMER, using the loadGenome.pl script. Command: loadGenome.pl -name TM1 -fasta /home/angad/Vikash/HiC_Cotton/TM1/TM1.fna -gtf /home/angad/Vikash/HiC_Cotton/TM1/output.gtf -org cotton
After loading my custon genome I used the annotateInteractions.pl script to annotate the interactions. Command: annotateInteractiobs.pl /home/angad/Vikash/HiC_Cotton/HOMER/annotation -res 10000
The output file generated has no information in the Detailed Annotation, Gene name, Gene alias columns although all these details are present in the gtf file. How can I annotate my interactions so that all the required information is present in these fields. I also tried loading the cotton genome using updateUCSCGenomeAnnotations.pl but that doesn't work either for cotton genome.
